# Emergency stop button for arduino mega code and circuit attached

Tags: arduino-mega, interrupt, code-review

I am trying to control steppers with pushbuttons and sensors.I want to add one more Pushbutton so that I can press it to stop the circuit and code running if something goes wrong in between. 
Below is the code I am using to run the steppers:

```cpp
int dirpin_T1 = 26;
int dirH_T1 = 28;
int steppin_T1 = 30;
int dirpin_F1 = 5;
int dirH_F1 = 6;
int steppin_F1 = 7;


int PB17ACW = 23;
int PB17ACCW = 22;
int PB17BCW = 25;
int PB17BCCW = 24;

int S01 = 34; // SENSOR INPUTS
int S02 = 35;
int S03 = 36;
int S04 = 37;


void setup()
{
  pinMode(dirpin_T1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(dirH_T1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(steppin_T1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(dirpin_F1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(dirH_F1 , OUTPUT);
  pinMode(steppin_F1, OUTPUT);


  pinMode(PB17ACW, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(PB17ACCW, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(PB17BCW, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(PB17BCCW, INPUT_PULLUP);

  pinMode(S01, INPUT);
  pinMode(S02, INPUT);
  pinMode(S03, INPUT);
  pinMode(S04, INPUT);
}

void loop()
{
  if (digitalRead(PB17ACW) == LOW &&  digitalRead(PB17ACCW) == LOW)
  {
    // STOP MOTOR WHEN NO KEY PRESSED
  }

  // FOR FORWARD ROTATION
  if (digitalRead(PB17ACW) == HIGH &&  digitalRead(PB17ACCW) == LOW )
  {
    digitalWrite(dirpin_T1, LOW );     // Set the direction.
    digitalWrite(dirH_T1, LOW);
    delay(1000);

    for (int i = 0; i < 32767; i++)     // Iterate for 4000 microsteps.(32767)
    {
      digitalWrite(steppin_T1, LOW);  // This LOW to HIGH change is what creates the
      digitalWrite(steppin_T1, HIGH); // "Rising Edge" so the easydriver knows to when to step.
      delayMicroseconds(50);
    }

    digitalWrite(dirpin_F1, LOW );     // Set the direction.
    digitalWrite(dirH_F1, LOW);
    delay(1000);
    do
    {
      digitalWrite(steppin_F1, LOW);  // This LOW to HIGH change is what creates the
      digitalWrite(steppin_F1, HIGH); // "Rising Edge" so the easydriver knows to when to step.
      delayMicroseconds(50);
    } while (digitalRead(S01) == LOW);

    delay(1000);

    digitalWrite(dirpin_T1, LOW );     // Set the direction.
    digitalWrite(dirH_T1, HIGH);
    delay(1000);

    for (int i = 0; i < 32767; i++)     // Iterate for 4000 microsteps.(32767)
    {
      digitalWrite(steppin_T1, LOW);  // This LOW to HIGH change is what creates the
      digitalWrite(steppin_T1, HIGH); // "Rising Edge" so the easydriver knows to when to step.
      delayMicroseconds(50);
    }
  }

  // FOR  BACKWARD ROTATION
  if (digitalRead(PB17ACW) == LOW &&  digitalRead(PB17ACCW) == HIGH)
  {
    digitalWrite(dirpin_T1, LOW );     // Set the direction.
    digitalWrite(dirH_T1, LOW);
    delay(1000);

    for (int i = 0; i < 32767; i++)     // Iterate for 4000 microsteps.(32767)
    {
      digitalWrite(steppin_T1, LOW);  // This LOW to HIGH change is what creates the
      digitalWrite(steppin_T1, HIGH); // "Rising Edge" so the easydriver knows to when to step.
      delayMicroseconds(50);
    }
    digitalWrite(dirpin_F1, LOW );     // Set the direction.
    digitalWrite(dirH_F1, HIGH);
    delay(1000);
    do
    {
      digitalWrite(steppin_F1, LOW);  // This LOW to HIGH change is what creates the
      digitalWrite(steppin_F1, HIGH); // "Rising Edge" so the easydriver knows to when to step.
      delayMicroseconds(50);
    } while (digitalRead(S02) == LOW);

    delay(1000);
    digitalWrite(dirpin_T1, LOW );     // Set the direction.
    digitalWrite(dirH_T1, HIGH);
    delay(1000);

    for (int i = 0; i < 32767; i++)     // Iterate for 4000 microsteps.(32767)
    {
      digitalWrite(steppin_T1, LOW);  // This LOW to HIGH change is what creates the
      digitalWrite(steppin_T1, HIGH); // "Rising Edge" so the easydriver knows to when to step.
      delayMicroseconds(50);
    }
  }
//WANT CODE TO STOP CODE ANYTIME I PRESS STOP BUTTON

}
```

Comment: This is a site where you ask questions. You don't just ask for code to be written for you. What is the question?

Comment: The simplest would be to use an interrupt triggered by the button and loop forever in the isr.

Answer (score 2):

The best option is to convert the `delay()` based code to a `millis()` based state machine. That way the code will never block and always be going through the loop and the place where you check wether that button was hit.

Then when that button is hit you transition to the E_STOP state which turns off all motors until the restart button is hit which goes to recalibrate the position if needed.

---

A more quick and dirty solution is to replace every every delay with

```
unsigned long current = millis();
while(milis() - current < delay){
    if(E_Stop()){
        stopped = true;
        return;
    }
}
```

And add a if check to bail out to every loop.

```
 for (/*...*/)      
  {
    //...
    delayMicroseconds(50);  
    if(E_Stop()){
        stopped = true;
        return;
    }
  }
```

At the start of `loop()` you then add a

```
if(stopped){
    //check for restart signal if true recalibrate otherwise return
}
```